# EKF Update Step measurement data doesnt fit state vector

Tags: slam, localization, ekf, estimation

I have an EKF SLAM Algorithm which tries to estimate the robots position (X,Y,Theta) + the X,Y coordinates of several landmarks. Like in the posted algorithm i have a range/bearing sensor. I understand every step until line 19. Why is there no conversion between my measurement and my mean? The same thing for line 20. Shouldnt be there a conversion so the "units" fit? "z(t)" is a range and bearing in my model (2 row vector). mu(t) is a 3+2N vector. Can somebody explain why this should still work?

[image: EKF SLAM Algorithm]

Comment: Multiplying by K serves as the "unit conversion".

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your fast respond! I think i will have to have look on K again and how it actually looks.